# Need help to figure out a equation to a placement system

Tags: combinatorics

There are 3(n) different items Square, Triangle, and Circle.

Square can be placed in one of 5(m) different boxes labeled with A1,A2,A3 etc.

Triangle can be placed in one of 5(m) more different boxes labeled with B1,B2,B3 etc.

Circle can be placed in one of 5(m) more different boxes labeled with C1,C2,C3 etc.

They can only be placed in one of the 5(m) boxes they are assigned.
IE: Square can only go in 1 box labeled A#

How many different combinations of each item going into boxes is there.

I believe the answer is 125 different ways but I don't know how to calculate that other then counting the combinations.

What's the equation used to calculate something like this no matter how many items(n) or boxes(m)?